# Copying a large html only site into DjangoCMS

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-cms

For those who have experienced Django CMS, are you aware of how suitable it might be to copy a large (500 page +) html only (no server side programming) for a large business into?

I have looked at their templating system and it seems to have its own language. As I am only an intermediate developer I want to avoid a large and messy migration process.

Can anyone advise how problematic copying a large site of this nature into this CMS would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question can't really be answered without knowing a lot more about the current website.

However, having ported a big semi-static website to django CMS I can tell you it is possible.

Here's how we did it:

1. Extract the "common" parts of the site design (as in, not content) and turn them into Django/django CMS templates.
2. Extract the content of your current site into some sort of intermediate format.
3. Write a script that uses cms.api [1] to turn the extracted content into a page tree and adds the appropriate plugins to those pages (this might be non-trivial as you have to figure out the correct plugin type from html content).

Make sure those steps are all automated, then run that script on the site. Tweak until the site converts mostly automated, then go in and fix the remaining issues manually.

[1] http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/extending_cms/api_references.html#cms-api